# Selecting a single file from an entire list of files based on pattern being matched

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to select a single file name from an entire list of files if the pattern matches. Files keep on changing every 15 days only a particular section of the file matches.
File name normally is `ABCD.NAD.RPT8.2018.10.12.TXT`. Part before `NAD` and after `RPT8` or `RPT9` Changes.

Pattern is `NAD.RPT8` or `NAD.RPT9`

I tried:

```
from os import walk
from os.path import splitext
import re
dolv_files = os.listdir(r'C:\DOLV')

for file_name in dolv_files:
  fname1=file_name.rsplit('.',4)[0]
   pattern = re.compile(r'NAD.RPT*')
   matches = [x for x in fname1 if pattern.match(x)]
   print(matches)
   first_fname=os.listdir(r'C:\DOLV')[0]
   print(first_fname)
```

It does not give me any results. It needs to pick up the first files with `NAD.RPT8` or `NAD.RPT9`

Any suggestions how to get this to work.

Regards,
Ren.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pathlib`:

```
from pathlib import Path
dolv_file_dir = Path('C:\DOLV')
matching_files_8 = dolv_file_dir.glob('*NAD.RPT8*')
matching_files_9 = dolv_file_dir.glob('*NAD.RPT9*')
first_match_8 = next(matching_files_8)
first_match_9 = next(matching_files_9)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It works. However it still give me RPT8, Does not give me RPT9. If i have Say RPT8 and RPT9 with multiple files it needs to give me the first of the file with these two extension individually. i tried `'*NAD.RPT[8-9]*'`i still get only RPT8

Comment: @RenLyke I've updated the answer to look for each type individually. If there are likely to be a large number of such extensions, you'd probably want to change the answer to loop through a list of such extensions, and build up the first item for each via a dict comprehension.

Comment: thanks for this it works. It is not possible to iterate and check the matching name.

Answer (score 0):

The `re.match` method matches only from the beginning of a string. To match anywhere in a string, you should use `re.search` instead. Also, it appears that you're using a glob pattern rather than a regex pattern. In a regex pattern `*` means to match 0 or more of the character preceding it, so `RPT*` actually matches `RP`, `RPT`, `RPTT`, `RPTTT` and so on, and `.` matches any character but the newline character, not just a dot. But more importantly, your `fname1` variable is a string, so if you iterate through `fname1` with `x`, then `x` is simply every single character of `fname1`. You should match directly against `fname1` instead. But then you're really just matching with a fixed string `NAD.RPT`, so there's no need for regex and you can simply use the `in` operator instead:

```
for file_name in dolv_files:
    if 'NAD.RPT' in file_name:
        first_name = file_name.split('.')[0]
        print(first_name)
```

Comment: i tried the same. when i print matches i get `[]` and for the first name i get a file that does not even match the pattern of NAD.RPT.

Comment: Thanks. It gives me the list of all the file with that extension. But not the 1st file in RPT8 and RPT9.